# AngularJS and Laravel relative paths

Tags: angularjs, laravel

Im using Laravel at the root folder on my shared hosting and put it's public folder at /public_html/admin. What changes I would make to Laravel settings so I can use it for rest calls by AngularJS in that folder ? Can anyone show me a basic example ? Tks

Answer (score 0):

You would need to modify your routes so that all incoming requests go to

www.yourdomain.com/admin/

and not

www.yourdomain.com/

you can do this with route group filters in laravel 4:

```
Route::group(array('prefix' => 'admin'), function()
{

    Route::get('/', function()
    {
        echo 'default admin route';
    });

    Route::get('user', function()
    {
        echo 'Do something view related';
    });

    Route::get('blog', function()
    {
        echo 'Do something view related';
    });

    Route::get('page', function()
    {
        echo 'Do something view related';
    });

});
```

also be sure to set a default route to redirect to your admin/ uri

```
Route::get('/', function()
{
    return Redirect::to('/admin');
});
```